# Cluster fomation of onos docker

Tags: docker, cluster-computing, onos, atomix

Now I want to create an onos cluster with docker and I followed the tutorial on the onos wiki: https://wiki.onosproject.org/display/ONOS/Notes+on+cluster+formation+for+Docker+instances

[tutorial on the onos wiki](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZXme.png)

I have a problem: how can I get the ip of an atomix container?

After I create an atomix container (`docker run -t -d --name atomix-2 atomix/atomix:3.1.5`), it stops immediately and I can't get its ip (`docker inspect atomix-2 | grep -i ipaddress`).

[my result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rX4fT.png)

Thank you for your answer.

I have tried `docker run -dit --name atomix-2 atomix/atomix:3.1.5`, but it doesn't work, still get the same result.

Comment: You may need to check out logs with `docker logs {container id}`.

Comment: @Vox Well, this is the output of `docker logs atomix-1`: `Exception in thread "main" io.atomix.utils.config.ConfigurationException: Cannot instantiate abstract type io.atomix.primitive.partition.PartitionGroupConfig`. It's obvious that here is a java exception but I don't find a solution on Google. Do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced this same problem. What I did is ignore this step (3) and continue until step 8 (`docker restart atomix-1`). Once this step is completed, repeat step 3 (`docker inspect atomix-1 | grep -i ipaddress`) to verify the ip address of all nodes in the atomix cluster.